# Finding image markers using mips

Tags: assembly, mips, marker, mars-simulator

I am new in Mars simulator.
I have been working on to finding markers on image by using mips. Here, the red zones are markers. The program doesn't detect red part. May you help me to solve this question?

The input BMP image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gatgi.png) (24-bit RGB) contains markers shown below. The image may
contain other elements. The task is to detect all markers of given type.
My hexadecimal details are:

```
#00000000   89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D
#00000010   00 00 01 40 00 00 00 F0 08 06 00 00
#00000020   6B 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 AE CE
#00000030   00 04 67 41 4D 41 00 00 B1 8F 0B FC
#00000040   00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 12 74 00 00
#00000050   66 1F 78 00 00 06 00 49 44 41 54 78
```

[image]

The markers are black and consist of two arms. Given marker type has width to height and these are constant. They can be various sizes. if the proportions of the dimensions of the arms are kept. The marker position is determined by the point where the arms intersect. Console window – plain text - subsequent lines contain the coordinates of the detected markers, eg. 5, 5. The point (0,0) is in the upper left corner of the image.
How can check the input and output errors. I'm gonna use 10 markers at most.

Table 1. Width to height ratio of different marker types.

```
Marker type
    W/H
    1 1
    2 1
    3 1
```

Input
BMP file source format: 24 bit RGB, width:320px, height: 240px,

```
.align 4
res:    .space 2
image:  .space BMP_FILE_SIZE

fname:  .asciiz "image.bmp"
    .text
main:
    jal read_bmp

    #put red pixel in bottom left corner    
    li  $a0, 0      #x
    li  $a1, 0      #y
    li  $a2, 0x00FF0000 #color - 00RRGGBB
    jal put_pixel

    #get pixel color - $a0=x, $a1=y, result $v0=0x00RRGGBB
    li  $a0, 0      #x
    li  $a1, 0      #y
    jal     get_pixel   #color - 
    
    #put green pixel one pixel above    
    li  $a0, 0      #x
    li  $a1, 1      #y
    li  $a2, 0x0000FF00 #color - 00RRGGBB
    jal put_pixel
    jal save_bmp

exit:   li  $v0,10      #Terminate the program
    syscall

read_bmp:
#description: 
#   reads the contents of a bmp file into memory
#arguments:
#   none
#return value: none
    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $ra to the stack
    sw $ra,($sp)
    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $s1
    sw $s1, ($sp)
#open file
    li $v0, 13
        la $a0, fname       #file name 
        li $a1, 0       #flags: 0-read file
        li $a2, 0       #mode: ignored
        syscall
    move $s1, $v0      # save the file descriptor
    
#check for errors - if the file was opened
#...

#read file
    li $v0, 14
    move $a0, $s1
    la $a1, image
    li $a2, BMP_FILE_SIZE
    syscall

#close file
    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s1
        syscall
    
    lw $s1, ($sp)       #restore (pop) $s1
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    lw $ra, ($sp)       #restore (pop) $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

save_bmp:
#description: 
#   saves bmp file stored in memory to a file
#arguments:
#   none
#return value: none
    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $ra to the stack
    sw $ra,($sp)
    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $s1
    sw $s1, ($sp)
#open file
    li $v0, 13
        la $a0, fname       #file name 
        li $a1, 1       #flags: 1-write file
        li $a2, 0       #mode: ignored
        syscall
    move $s1, $v0      # save the file descriptor
    
#check for errors - if the file was opened
#...

#save file
    li $v0, 15
    move $a0, $s1
    la $a1, image
    li $a2, BMP_FILE_SIZE
    syscall

#close file
    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s1
        syscall
    
    lw $s1, ($sp)       #restore (pop) $s1
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    lw $ra, ($sp)       #restore (pop) $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra


# ============================================================================
put_pixel:
#description: 
#   sets the color of specified pixel
#arguments:
#   $a0 - x coordinate
#   $a1 - y coordinate - (0,0) - bottom left corner
#   $a2 - 0RGB - pixel color
#return value: none

    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $ra to the stack
    sw $ra,($sp)

    la $t1, image + 10  #adress of file offset to pixel array
    lw $t2, ($t1)       #file offset to pixel array in $t2
    la $t1, image       #adress of bitmap
    add $t2, $t1, $t2   #adress of pixel array in $t2
    
    #pixel address calculation
    mul $t1, $a1, BYTES_PER_ROW #t1= y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    move $t3, $a0       
    sll $a0, $a0, 1
    add $t3, $t3, $a0   #$t3= 3*x
    add $t1, $t1, $t3   #$t1 = 3x + y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    add $t2, $t2, $t1   #pixel address 
    
    #set new color
    sb $a2,($t2)        #store B
    srl $a2,$a2,8
    sb $a2,1($t2)       #store G
    srl $a2,$a2,8
    sb $a2,2($t2)       #store R

    lw $ra, ($sp)       #restore (pop) $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
get_pixel:
#description: 
#   returns color of specified pixel
#arguments:
#   $a0 - x coordinate
#   $a1 - y coordinate - (0,0) - bottom left corner
#return value:
#   $v0 - 0RGB - pixel color

    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $ra to the stack
    sw $ra,($sp)

    la $t1, image + 10  #adress of file offset to pixel array
    lw $t2, ($t1)       #file offset to pixel array in $t2
    la $t1, image       #adress of bitmap
    add $t2, $t1, $t2   #adress of pixel array in $t2
    
    #pixel address calculation
    mul $t1, $a1, BYTES_PER_ROW #t1= y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    move $t3, $a0       
    sll $a0, $a0, 1
    add $t3, $t3, $a0   #$t3= 3*x
    add $t1, $t1, $t3   #$t1 = 3x + y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    add $t2, $t2, $t1   #pixel address 
    
    #get color
    lbu $v0,($t2)       #load B
    lbu $t1,1($t2)      #load G
    sll $t1,$t1,8
    or $v0, $v0, $t1
    lbu $t1,2($t2)      #load R
        sll $t1,$t1,16
    or $v0, $v0, $t1
                    
    lw $ra, ($sp)       #restore (pop) $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

Comment: So what is your question? What is your algorithm? I don't see any relevant code. Is the marker red (as you say in the first paragraph) or black? What is the red block then?

Comment: I could not detect the red part. It shows me only black part.